# Unable to open .tgz file

Tags: tar

using a Mac, downloaded a file 'circos-0.69-8.tgz' and tried to untar using the following command -

```
tar xvfz circos-0.69-8.tgz
```

And I get the following error:

```
"Error opening archive" Failed to open 'circos-0.69-8.tgz'
```

Is there something I'm not getting? Apparently there's no such file, here's some other things I tried:

```
gunzip circos-0.69-8.tgz
gunzip: can't stat: circos-0.69-8.tgz (circos-0.69-8.tgz.gz): No such file or directory
```

as well as:

```
circos -version
circos | v 0.69-8 | 15 Jun 2019 | Perl 5.018002
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer as mac unzips or untars the file automatically in Finder, code is unnecessary, newbie mistake, carry on!